# Edit ace editor autocomlpeter

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, ace-editor

I can edit autocompleter output as an example if user write con so autocompleter lists for example closing but I want to autocompleter lists only words which have letter c,o,n immediately adjacent side by side. For example content.

Comment: Can you provide a proper example? The example provided is unclear

Comment: @Harshapps
So If I write "se" autocompleter lists for example words: set,case, super, escape,...
But I want to only words set, case, where are letters  "se" immediately adjacent side by side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an insertMatch method on your completer. You can put your display text in the value property on the match.

```
insertMatch: function(editor, data) {
    editor.completer.insertMatch({value: data.caption});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set exactMatch option to true on autocompelter https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/lib/ace/autocomplete.js#L431, but editor doesn't forward it. Try opening issue on ace bug tracker asking to add support for that